# Import a PDF from within a page (Feeds / Mailhandler)

Tags: files, feeds

I am using Mailhandler to import quite a bit of content. The one piece I'm not able to get is a pdf.

The email body contains five links. The last link goes to a page that has an iframe with a source of the pdf I want. Example:

```
<iframe src="/files/20394.pdf">
```

However, the link in the email does not seem to have "20394" anywhere in it, so I can't even generate the link to the pdf myself.

At the end, then, I would have the importer import that link as a file.

Is there any other way to grab that pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using curl to get the source code then preg_match to pull the URL. I haven't actually gotten the pdf, though, because it's using a form to generate the pdf. However, that's a different issue, so this question is answered.